# ORACLE : how to create dynamic update procedure depending on parameters?

Tags: oracle, parameters, procedure

i want to make update procedure that updated the column of the table depends on parameter.

is this possible update the field depending on input parameter?

this is the example procedure that i've made:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure(parameter in varchar2)
IS errormessage varchar2(255);
  BEGIN
  UPDATE table
SET table.parameter = 'newvalue'
END;
```

and it doesn't works.
please help.

Comment: so `parameter` is column which needs to be updated. Do you wan to hardcode all columns as `newvalue`?

Comment: no @Utsav i'll selected that newvalue from another table, and code that you post, it's working! thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Handled SQL Injection scenario.

You need `execute immediate` as `parameter` will be used as column name.

Note: Remember you are running update statement without where clause which will update all the rows.

Also you cannot pass a numeric column name as the value `newvalue` is a string. So If you want to handle it, then use if else condition and check for column data type before running update statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc12(column_name in varchar2)
IS
v_count integer;
  BEGIN
  select count(*) into v_count from (select column_name as txt from dual) where regexp_like (txt,'[,|=|;]');
  if v_count =0 then
  execute immediate 'UPDATE tbl1 SET '||column_name||' = ''newvalue''';
  else
  dbms_output.put_line('SQL Injection detected. Exiting');
 end if;
END;




select * from tbl1;

+------+
| col1 |
+------+
| abc  |
| pqr  |
| xyz  |
+------+

call proc12('col1');

select * from tbl1;

+----------+
|   col1   |
+----------+
| newvalue |
| newvalue |
| newvalue |
+----------+

call proc12('balance=10000, col1');
SQL Injection detected. Exiting
```

Comment: Better use `execute immediate 'UPDATE tbl1 SET '||column_name||' = :val' USING newvalue;`

Comment: This is a security issue (sql injection) when used on production systems, e.g. `call proc12('balance=10000, col1')` will update balance to 10000 for all rows.

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss - Thanks. I added logic to handle it.